# Gradle: Cant exclude one of two log4j dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

### Occuring error

While trying to build an android studio project with gradle i recieve this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForPlainDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException:
Duplicate files copied in APK org/apache/log4j/lf5/config/defaultconfig.properties

File1: ...\app\libs\tn5250j.jar
File2: ...\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\xxx\xxx\jars\libs\log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

In two included `.jars` the library `log4j` is used. I must include both libs to my android application. One of them is an `.aar` file, the other is a `.jar`.

### Gradle settings

Dependencies from my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile 'xxx@aar'
    releaseCompile 'xxx@aar'
    
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.8.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/tn5250j.jar')
}
```

Packaging options from my `build.gradle`:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what `tn5250j.jar` is but it looks like it's an UBER jar which is packing `log4j` inside. You could either exclude the `log4j` dependency from your build (since it's packed inside `tn5250j.jar`) or you tweak `tn5250j.jar` to remove `log4j`and use the "tweaked" jar instead. Eg:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile files("$buildDir/tweaked/tn5250j-tweaked.jar")
}
task tweakTn5250j(type: Zip) {
    from zipTree('libs/tn5250j.jar').matching {
        exclude 'org/apache/log4j/**'
    }
    destinationDir = "$buildDir/tweaked"
    archiveName = 'tn5250j-tweaked.jar'
}
classes.dependsOn tweakTn5250j
```